# How to check if a String contains only ASCII?

Tags: java, string, character-encoding, ascii

The call `Character.isLetter(c)` returns `true` if the character is a letter. But is there a way to quickly find if a `String` only contains the base characters of ASCII?

Answer (score 138, accepted):

From [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) 19.0 onward, you may use:

```
boolean isAscii = CharMatcher.ascii().matchesAllOf(someString);
```

This uses the [`matchesAllOf(someString)`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html#matchesAllOf(java.lang.CharSequence)) method which relies on the factory method [`ascii()`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html#ascii()) rather than the now deprecated `ASCII` singleton.

Here ASCII includes all ASCII characters *including* the non-printable characters lower than `0x20` (space) such as tabs, line-feed / return but also `BEL` with code `0x07` and `DEL` with code `0x7F`.

This code incorrectly uses characters rather than code points, even if code points are indicated in the comments of earlier versions. Fortunately, the characters required to create code point with a value of `U+010000` or over uses two surrogate characters with a value outside of the ASCII range. So the method still succeeds in testing for ASCII, even for strings containing emoji's.

For earlier Guava versions without the `ascii()` method you may write:

```
boolean isAscii = CharMatcher.ASCII.matchesAllOf(someString);
```

Comment: +1 Although it's good if you don't need another third-party library, Colin's answer is much shorter and much more readable. Suggesting third-party libraries is perfectly OK and should not be punished with a negative vote.

Comment: I should also point out that CharMatchers are really incredibly powerful and can do waaaay more than this. In addition there are many more predefined CharMatchers besides ASCII, and great factory methods for creating custom ones.

Comment: `CharMatcher.ASCII` is deprecated now and about to be remove in June 2018.

Answer (score 129):

You can do it with  [java.nio.charset.Charset](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html).

```
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

public class StringUtils {
  
  public static boolean isPureAscii(String v) {
    return Charset.forName("US-ASCII").newEncoder().canEncode(v);
    // or "ISO-8859-1" for ISO Latin 1
    // or StandardCharsets.US_ASCII with JDK1.7+
  }

  public static void main (String args[])
    throws Exception {

     String test = "Réal";
     System.out.println(test + " isPureAscii() : " + StringUtils.isPureAscii(test));
     test = "Real";
     System.out.println(test + " isPureAscii() : " + StringUtils.isPureAscii(test));
     
     /*
      * output :
      *   Réal isPureAscii() : false
      *   Real isPureAscii() : true
      */
  }
}
```

Answer (score 84):

Here is another way not depending on a library but using a regex.

You can use this single line:

```
text.matches("\\A\\p{ASCII}*\\z")
```

Whole example program:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char nonAscii = 0x00FF;
        String asciiText = "Hello";
        String nonAsciiText = "Buy: " + nonAscii;
        System.out.println(asciiText.matches("\\A\\p{ASCII}*\\z"));
        System.out.println(nonAsciiText.matches("\\A\\p{ASCII}*\\z"));
    }
}
```

Understanding the regex :

- li `\\A` : Beginning of input
- `\\p{ASCII}` : Any ASCII character
- `*` : all repetitions
- `\\z` : End of input

Comment: \\A - Beginning of input ... \\p{ASCII}* -  Any ASCII character any times ...\\z - End of input

Comment: @ArneDeutsch Do you mind if I improve the answer and include references to `\P{Print}` and `\P{Graph}` + a description? Why do you need `\A` and `\z`?

Comment: What is that regex? I know that $ is end of string, ^ is start, never heard of either of \\A \\p \\z, could you please attach the reference to javadoc?

Comment: @deathangel908 \A is start of input.  \z is end of input. ^ and $ behave differently in MULTILINE mode, and DOTALL changes behavior of \A and \z.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/3652402/1003157

Answer (score 65):

Iterate through the string and make sure all the characters have a value less than 128.

Java Strings are conceptually encoded as UTF-16.  In UTF-16, the ASCII character set is encoded as the values 0 - 127 and the encoding for any non ASCII character (which may consist of more than one Java char) is guaranteed not to include the numbers 0 - 127

Comment: With Java 1.8 you can do: `str.chars().allMatch(c -> c < 128)`

Comment: If you want printable characters you may want to test for `c >= 0x20 && c < 0x7F` as the first 32 values of the 7 bit encoding are control characters and the final value (0x7F) is `DEL`.

Answer (score 17):

Or you copy the code from the [IDN](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/IDN.html) class.

```
// to check if a string only contains US-ASCII code point
//
private static boolean isAllASCII(String input) {
    boolean isASCII = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        int c = input.charAt(i);
        if (c > 0x7F) {
            isASCII = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return isASCII;
}
```

Comment: This even works with 2-char-unicode because the 1st-char is >= U+D800

Comment: But note that it includes non-printable characters in ASCII (which is correct, but it may not be expected). It is of course possible to directly use `return false` instead of using `isASCII = false` and `break`.

Comment: This is code from Oracle JDK. Copying might cause legal issues.

Answer (score 11):

commons-lang3 from Apache contains valuable utility/convenience methods for all kinds of 'problems',  including this one.

```
System.out.println(StringUtils.isAsciiPrintable("!@£$%^&!@£$%^"));
```

Comment: Be aware that isAsciiPrintable returns false if the string contains tab or line feed characters (\t \r \n).

Comment: @TampaHaze thats because internally, its checking for every character value to be between 32 to 127. I think thats wrong. We should check from 0 to 127

Comment: @therealprashant if the method name was isAscii I would agree with you.  But the method being named isAsciiPrintable implies that they may have purposely excluded characters 0 to 31.

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
for (char c: string.toCharArray()){
  if (((int)c)>127){
    return false;
  } 
}
return true;
```

Comment: "Try this" always gets a downvote. What does this *do*? What is included and what isn't? Would get a downvote because you double the size in memory too, by the way.

Answer (score 3):

```
private static boolean isASCII(String s) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) 
        if (s.charAt(i) > 127) 
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Code only answer, please indicate what this does, i.e. that it includes non-printable characters and a undefined character (0x7F) if you perform this check.

Comment: This one may have bit me after my long-running program failed to find any characters of interest.  `charAt` returns a `char`.  Can you directly test if a type `char` is greater than an int without converting to an int, first, or does your test automatically do the coversion?  Maybe you can and maybe it does?  I went ahead and converted this to an int like so: `if ((int)s.charAt(i) > 127)`. Not sure if my results are any different but I feel better about letting it run.  We'll see :-\

Comment: This seems to work and was the fasted way for me in a quick series of rather unscientific local micro-benchmarks. The similar approach with "toCharArray" allocates and array and thus is performing worse than this one. One further smalll optimization seems to be to extract the lenght() into a local variable.

Answer (score 3):

This will return true if String only contains ASCII characters and false when it does not

```
Charset.forName("US-ASCII").newEncoder().canEncode(str)
```

If You want to remove non ASCII , here is the snippet:

```
if(!Charset.forName("US-ASCII").newEncoder().canEncode(str)) {
                        str = str.replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "");
                    }
```

Comment: Vanilla Java, simple to read, what's not to like with this answer?

Although, to avoid typos in "US-ASCII":


`StandardCharsets.US_ASCII.newEncoder().canEncode(str)`

Comment: Instead of `[^\\p{ASCII}]`, you can simplify it: `\\P{ASCII}`. Capital \P is complement of lowercase \p.

Answer (score 3):

In Java 8 and above, one can use [`String#codePoints`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html#codePoints--) in conjunction with [`IntStream#allMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#allMatch-java.util.function.IntPredicate-).

```
boolean allASCII = str.codePoints().allMatch(c -> c < 128);
```

Answer (score 3):

In Kotlin:

```
fun String.isAsciiString() : Boolean =
    this.toCharArray().none { it < ' ' || it > '~' }
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through the string, and use charAt() to get the char.  Then treat it as an int, and see if it has a unicode value (a superset of ASCII) which you like.

Break at the first you don't like.

Answer (score 0):

It was possible. Pretty problem.

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder;

public class EncodingTest {

    static CharsetEncoder asciiEncoder = Charset.forName("US-ASCII")
            .newEncoder();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String testStr = "¤EÀsÆW°ê»Ú®i¶T¤¤¤ß3¼Ó®i¶TÆU2~~KITEC 3/F Rotunda 2";
        String[] strArr = testStr.split("~~", 2);
        int count = 0;
        boolean encodeFlag = false;

        do {
            encodeFlag = asciiEncoderTest(strArr[count]);
            System.out.println(encodeFlag);
            count++;
        } while (count < strArr.length);
    }

    public static boolean asciiEncoderTest(String test) {
        boolean encodeFlag = false;
        try {
            encodeFlag = asciiEncoder.canEncode(new String(test
                    .getBytes("ISO8859_1"), "BIG5"));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return encodeFlag;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
//return is uppercase or lowercase
public boolean isASCIILetter(char c) {
  return (c > 64 && c < 91) || (c > 96 && c < 123);
}
```

Comment: A code only answer with 4 magics, and no explanation what it *does*. Please adjust.