# Java regex replaceAll multiline

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

I have a problem with the replaceAll for a multiline string:

```
String regex = "\\s*/\\*.*\\*/";
String testWorks = " /** this should be replaced **/ just text";
String testIllegal = " /** this should be replaced \n **/ just text";

testWorks.replaceAll(regex, "x"); 
testIllegal.replaceAll(regex, "x");
```

The above works for testWorks, but not for testIllegal!?
Why is that and how can I overcome this? I need to replace something like a comment /* ... */ that spans multiple lines.

Comment: And what about this string: `"String s = \"/*\"; /* comment */"`

Comment: Well the point is that the mathing regex should match only in the beginning of the string. Now it looks like this:(?s)^\\s*/\\*.*\\*/ Not sure though, if to make it reluctant (?s)^\\s*/\\*.*?\\*/

Answer (score 99, accepted):

You need to use the `Pattern.DOTALL` flag to say that the dot should match newlines. e.g.

```
Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.DOTALL).matcher(testIllegal).replaceAll("x")
```

or alternatively specify the flag in the pattern using `(?s)` e.g.

```
String regex = "(?s)\\s*/\\*.*\\*/";
```

Comment: This is the best solution because it does not interact with the regex string itself, you just specify a flag. I did not know that, Thanks!

Comment: If you have multiple "multi-line" comments, this method will remove text between those comments as well. Use the method posted by Boris instead.

Answer (score 16):

Add `Pattern.DOTALL` to the compile, or `(?s)` to the pattern.

This would work

```
String regex = "(?s)\\s*/\\*.*\\*/";
```

See 
[Match multiline text using regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651725/match-multiline-text-using-regular-expression?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work in combination with String.replaceAll. :(

Answer (score 7):

The meta character `.` matches any character other than newline. That is why your regex does not work for multi line case.

To fix this replace `.` with `[\d\D]` that matches **any** character including newline.

[**Code In Action**](http://www.ideone.com/5ZYJb)

Comment: Swapping in `[\d\D]` for `.` (which normally means `[^\n]`, at least in `Pattern.UNIX_LINES` mode) strikes me as inappropriate because it is not obvious what it is doing, because it is 6 chars for 1, and because there are other ways of doing this.