# Remove filepaths from a text

Tags: java, android, regex, parsing

I have a long text which contains paths to some files.

What I want to do is to remove the paths from it.
The filepaths are all something like:

```
some text 1
/all/extraItems/Java/.Scripts/.Sample1.js
some text 2
/all/extraItems/Android/.Scripts/.Sample2.js
some text 3
```

I know that using **"^/all"** will select a sentence that starts with **/all** and also **.js$** for ending with **.js**. But I cannot merge these together to select the whole filepath.

After all the Regular Expression should be placed on the following code to remove the Paths.

```
text.replaceAll(<RegularExpression> , "");
```

Who can I write the regEx for it? Is there any tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to "merge" them you will have to match the characters in between, as well:

```
^/all.*?\.js$
```

`.` matches any character, `*` repeats the previous character 0 or more times, `?` makes the repetition ungreedy, avoiding a match going over multiple lines. Since you are using Java, you need to escape the backslash once more in your string:

```
"^/all.*?\\.js$"
```

If you do not use the multiline option already (which you actually need to do, for `^/all` and `js$` to work on your input), you can do that like this:

```
"(?m)^/all.*?\\.js$"
```

Comment: that doesn't help me in fixing it ;)... what happens instead?

Comment: I even try it on Notepad++ and that select nothing. `^/all` works individually.

Comment: @mammadalius, works fine for me in Notepad++. Make sure you have the latest version (Notepad++ 6), the previous regex engine had a few issues. To use the regex in Java you need to double the `\` (sorry, I should have mentioned that), and as Fake.It.Til.U.Make.It mentioned, you need to activate multiline mode, but from your two working examples, I thought you had already done that (otherwise `^/all` and `js$` would not work either). I updated my answer, have a look!

Answer (score 1):

use `.*?` to merge them together

```
^/all.*?\.js$
```

So,the `regex` says match 0 to n number of characters i.e `.*?` which begins with `all` and ends with `\.js`..you need to escape `.` since `.` means match any character...

Dont forget to use **multiline option**

Comment: @mammadalius multiline option matches `\n`..more info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4154239/java-regex-replaceall-multiline)

Comment: i just add another back slash to avoid compiler error "^/all.*?\\.js$" but nothing removed from my text