# Replace Host in an HTTP request string

Tags: java, regex, string, http

Given an HTTP request:

```
Client: GET /Default.aspx HTTP/1.1
Accept: image/gif, image/jpeg, image/pjpeg, image/pjpeg, application/x-shockwave
-flash, application/x-ms-application, application/x-ms-xbap, application/vnd.ms-
xpsdocument, application/xaml+xml, */*
Accept-Language: en-us
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET
 CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.5.21022)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: logan-pc:8080
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

How can I change the `Host` line programmatically? I've tried using regex (using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4154239/java-regex-replaceall-multiline) as a guide) and can't figure out the right pattern.

This is the pattern I'm using now:

```
".*?Host:.*?:" + <dynamic port number goes here>+ ".*?"
```

When compiling the pattern I use the `Pattern.DOTALL` flag as suggested in the linked question.

**UPDATE:** I get the request string directly from the browser, this is what I'm using now:

```
int len = 0;
while((len = ConnHandler.this.clientIn.read(buf)) > 0)
{
    System.out.println(".*?Host:.*?:" + ConnHandler.this.serverport+".*?");
    String in = new String(buf, 0, len);
    in.replaceAll(".*?Host:.*?:" + ConnHandler.this.serverport+".*?", "localhost:" + ConnHandler.this.serverport);
    //...
}
```

Yet it is still not working.

Comment: Could you please share output for String in and ConnHandler.this.serverport value?

Comment: In = the request in the question, ConnHandler.this.serverport in this case = 8080.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pattern is correct.
This code works for me:

```
String string = "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\nHost: logan-pc:8080\nConnection: Keep-Alive";
System.out.println(string.replaceAll(".*?Host:.*?:8080.*?", "Host: NEW_HOST:8080"));
```

Output:

> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
>
> Host: NEW_HOST:8080
>
> Connection: Keep-Alive

Comment: Still not working for me. I'm getting the request string directly from the browser via an input stream and redirecting it to another, perhaps there's something else going on in there. I'll update my question.

Comment: Solved it. I just needed to `in = in.replaceAll(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Replace: `/static/cache/gettheme_whiteboard_`
with: `/static/cache/gettheme_cust`