# Regex to replace spring:message tags with th:text equivalent

Tags: java, regex, eclipse, thymeleaf

Using the Eclipse Search function `CTRL-H`, what would be a regex to replace all occurrences of `<spring:message />` tags like:

```
<label>
    <spring:message code="name" />
</label>
<h1><spring:message code="title" /></h1>
```

with:

```
<label th:text="#{name}"></label>
<h1 th:text="#{title}"></h1>
```

**Edit**

Nice would be if the regex would also handle replacement of:

```
<label class="lalala"><spring:message code="name" /></label>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this generic one:

```
<([^>]+)>\s*<\s*spring:message\s+code="([^"]*)"[^<]+<\/\1>
```

and replace by:

```
<\1 th:text="#\{\2\}"><\/\1>
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CokN87/1/)

You may have to escape the backslaseh for your IDE like this:

regex:

```
(?s)<([^>]+)>\\s*<\\s*spring:message\\s+code=\"([^\"]*)\"[^<]+<\\/\\1>
```

subst

```
<\\1 th:text=\"#\\{\\2\\}\"><\\/\\1>
```

Comment: The generic one works, thank you very much. One small detail: You missed the #, it should be <\1 th:text="\#{\2\}"><\/\1>

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
(?s)<label>[^<]*<spring:message code="([^"]*)" */>[^<]*</label>
```

->

```
<label th:text="#{$1}"></label>
```

and

```
<h1><spring:message code="([^"]*)" /></h1>
```

->

```
<h1 th:text="#{$1}"></h1>
```

(The (?s) is there to allow multiline matches: [multiline search replace with regexp in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16704599/multiline-search-replace-with-regexp-in-eclipse))