# Multiline search in eclipse

Tags: regex, eclipse

Presently I am working in eclipse. I have some buttons with some attribute like.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-customid="btn_select">
    <span>Select</span>
</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" 
    data-customid="btn_select">
    <span>Select</span>
</button>
```

when i am search using

```
<button * data
```

the searching is perfect with one line button but multi-line buttons not support this regular expression. How to possible search with multi-line regular expression.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31410054/2670892)

Comment: `<button[^>]*data`

Comment: yes this is working