# Searching for a method with a specific parameter count (in Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to use the Eclipse search to find all method calls for a method which takes a variable argument count, like this: `public void myMethod(String s, Object o, String... categories)` and get all which have specific counts of the optional parameter at the end.

So for example i would like to find all occurrences of `myMethod("test", niceObject)` when i want those without any optional parameters. I know atleast this part can be done via regex, but this will stop working as soon as someone has split it up into multiple lines (or my regex-fu isn't strong enough :) ).

Any suggestions appreciated, be it using the eclipse built-in search functionality or a good regex which can deal with multiline method calls-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(?s)foo\(([^,]+,){2}[^,]+\);` matches calls to a method `foo` with 3 parameters.

Here are the details:

- `(?s)` [is used for matching multiple lines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31410054/10226142)
- `[^,]+` [matches everything but `,`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2013150/10226142)
- `([^,]+,){2}` matches a list of 2 arguments; replace 2 with the number of arguments you want - 1
- `[^,]+\);` matches the last argument, followed here by `);`

Answer (score 1):

Using the Eclipse File Search this one should work with multiline method calls (with 2 being the vararg count):

```
myMethod\([^,]+,[^,]+(,[^,]+){2}\)
```