# Groovy regex when replacing tokens in file

Tags: regex, string, replace, groovy

I have a text file that has the token "`%%#%`" located all over the place inside of it. I am trying to write a quick-and-dirty Groovy shell script to replace all instances of "`%%#%`" with a dollar sign "`$`".

So far I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
File f = new File('path/to/my/file.txt')
f.withWriter{ it << f.text.replace("%%#%", "$") }
```

But when I run this script, nothing happens (no exceptions **and** no string replacement). I wonder if any of the characters I'm searching for, or the dollar sign itself, is being interpreted as a special char by the regex engine under the hood. In any event, **Where am I going awry?**

Comment: Groovy strings don't seem to have a `.replace` method, just `.replaceAll` and `.replaceFirst`.

Comment: try '$' instead of "$"..

Comment: if this is all your script has to do also consider using sed `sed -ie 's/%%#%/$/g' path/to/my/file.txt`

Comment: I am not sure on the file input, but use replaceAll here, `.replaceAll('%%#%', Matcher.quoteReplacement('$'))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to read the file content first, and then write on the file. Seems like `withWriter` erases the file contents:

```
def f = new File('/tmp/file.txt')
text = f.text
f.withWriter { w ->
  w << text.replaceAll("(?s)%%#%", /\$/)
}
```

You might want to do a [per line read](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Reading+Files+Line+by+Line) if the file is too large. Otherwise, you can use that [multiline `(?s)` regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4154239/java-regex-replaceall-multiline).

Note I escaped `$`, because `replace` and `replaceAll` behaves differently, in a sense that `replace` accepts a `char` and, thus, will be unaffected by regex strings, whereas `replaceAll` will need escaping.

Here is my test:

```
$ echo "%%#%
aaaa
bbbb
cccc%%#%dddd" > file.txt && groovy Subst.groovy && cat file.txt 
$
aaaa
bbbb
cccc$dddd
```

Comment: What do you mean by **then write on the file**?  What is the code for that?

Comment: read the file content: `f.text`. Write on the file: `f.withWriter { ... }`