# Split text with Java-Regex in pairs with Regex over several lines

Tags: java, regex, split

I have following text:

```
my-widget{
  color: #{mycolors.getColors(1)}
}
...
my-tridget{
  color: #{mycolors.getColors(2)}
  ...
}
...
```

I want to split the text in pairs, where the delimiter is #{mycolors.getColors()} and the text between previous delimeter and current delimiter will be saved. E.g. for such pairs:

Pair 1:
      **text:**   my-widget{
      color:
      **number:** 1

Pair 2:
      **text:** }
    ...
    my-tridget{
      color:
    **number:**
          2

What I am used so far,

```
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.*)#\\{mycolors.getColor\\(([0-9])\\)\\}", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE|Pattern.MULTILINE);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(data);

 while (m.find){
     String number = m.group(2).toLowerCase().trim();
     String text = m.group(1);          
 }
```

But number and text will be to:

**text:**   color: **number:** 1

**text:**   color: **number:** 2

So the text doesn't go over several lines. How can I achieve this ? (The Pattern.DOTALL in addtion to Pattern.MULTILINE didn't help me)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651725/match-multiline-text-using-regular-expression

Comment: @Simon Sorry but I don't know how I can use your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Some mistakes you're making:**

1. To match text across multiple lines you need to use `Pattern.DOTALL` instead of `Pattern.MULTILINE`
2. Instead of `.*` make it non greedy `.*?`
3. Your text has string `getColors` but you have `getColor` in your regex

**Following regex pattern should work out for you:**

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.*?)#\\{mycolors.getColors\\((\\d+)\\)\\}", 
                            Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE|Pattern.DOTALL);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've tried to change the regex and it seems to do what I want to.