# Java regex not picking up multiple occurences of string

Tags: java, regex, string, multiline

I know that there have been variations of questions answered here

- [Match multiline text using regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651725/match-multiline-text-using-regular-expression)
- [Split text with Java-Regex in pairs with Regex over several lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18827874/split-text-with-java-regex-in-pairs-with-regex-over-several-lines?lq=1)
- [Match multiline text using regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651725/match-multiline-text-using-regular-expression)

I have tried to go through the solutions and come up with a regular expression for my needs. I have a string of text over multiple lines with neither a fixed starting location nor an ending location for a particular line.

```
<a name='bill_pay' href='javascript:goto(&#39;billpay&#39;);' class='fsdnav-top-menu-item'>Bill Pay <span class='fsdnav-ada-hidden'>link and menu. Press enter to navigate to this link. Press control + space to open submenu.

To move through submenu items press tab and then press up or down arrow.</span> </a>
<a name='bill_pay' href='javascript:goto(&#39;findmyinfo&#39;);' class='fsdnav-top-menu-item'>
Bill Pay <span class='fsdnav-ada-hidden'>link and menu. Press enter to navigate to this link. Press control + space to open submenu.

To move through submenu items press tab and then press up or down arrow.</span> </a>
<a name='bill_pay' href='#' onClick='OOLPopUp(&#39;/myaccounts/brain/redirect.go?target=findmyroutingnumber&#39;,&#39;ool&#39;,&#39;currentPage&#39;);return false;' class='fsdnav-top-menu-item'>
Bill Pay <span class='fsdnav-ada-hidden'>link and menu. Press enter to navigate to this link. Press control + space to open submenu.
To move through submenu items press tab and then press up or down arrow.</span> </a>
```

I would like to extract the following the contents from `javascript:goto(&quot;link&quot;)` (what ever link value represents) There are multiple such occurrences in the above regex, but the regex that I am using returns just a single occurrence. I would like to return all of it. My code block is given below

```
private static final Pattern PATTERN_WITH_ASCII_QUOTES =
    Pattern.compile("^.*goto\\(&#39;(\\w+)&#39;\\).*",
        Pattern.MULTILINE|Pattern.DOTALL);

// "str" is the string representation of the text above.
Matcher m = PATTERN_WITH_ASCII_QUOTES.matcher(str);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

The resultant output is always `findmyinfo` and nothing else.

**UPDATE** - The desired outputs are

```
 billpay (from javascript:goto(&#39;billpay&#39;);)
 findmyinfo (from javascript:goto(&#39;findmyinfo&#39;);)
```

I would also like to to extract

```
/myaccounts/brain/redirect.go?target=findmyroutingnumber&#39;,&#39;ool&#39;,&#39;currentPage from OOLPopUp(&#39;/myaccounts/brain/redirect.go?target=findmyroutingnumber&#39;,&#39;ool&#39;,&#39;currentPage&#39;)
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `OLLPopUp` and `goto` into a non-capturing group in-order to get the first, second and third values.

```
 ^.*?(?:goto|OOLPopUp)\(&#39;(.*?)&#39;\).*
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/lJ4lF9/3)

```
String s = "<a name='bill_pay' href='javascript:goto(&#39;billpay&#39;);' class='fsdnav-top-menu-item'>Bill Pay <span class='fsdnav-ada-hidden'>link and menu. Press enter to navigate to this link. Press control + space to open submenu.\n" + 
        "To move through submenu items press tab and then press up or down arrow.</span> </a>\n" +
        "<a name='bill_pay' href='javascript:goto(&#39;findmyinfo&#39;);' class='fsdnav-top-menu-item'>\n" +
        "<a name='bill_pay' href='#' onClick='OOLPopUp(&#39;/myaccounts/brain/redirect.go?target=findmyroutingnumber&#39;,&#39;ool&#39;,&#39;currentPage&#39;);return false;' class='fsdnav-top-menu-item'>\n" +
        "Bill Pay <span class='fsdnav-ada-hidden'>link and menu. Press enter to navigate to this link. Press control + space to open submenu.";
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("^.*?(?:goto|OOLPopUp)\\(&#39;(.*?)&#39;\\).*", Pattern.MULTILINE);
 Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(s);
 while(matcher.find()){
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

**Output:**

```
billpay
findmyinfo
/myaccounts/brain/redirect.go?target=findmyroutingnumber&#39;,&#39;ool&#39;,&#39;currentPage
```

**OR**

```
String s = "<a name='bill_pay' href='javascript:goto(&#39;billpay&#39;);' class='fsdnav-top-menu-item'>Bill Pay <span class='fsdnav-ada-hidden'>link and menu. Press enter to navigate to this link. Press control + space to open submenu.\n" + 
        "To move through submenu items press tab and then press up or down arrow.</span> </a>\n" +
        "<a name='bill_pay' href='javascript:goto(&#39;findmyinfo&#39;);' class='fsdnav-top-menu-item'>\n" +
        "<a name='bill_pay' href='#' onClick='OOLPopUp(&#39;/myaccounts/brain/redirect.go?target=findmyroutingnumber&#39;,&#39;ool&#39;,&#39;currentPage&#39;);return false;' class='fsdnav-top-menu-item'>\n" +
        "Bill Pay <span class='fsdnav-ada-hidden'>link and menu. Press enter to navigate to this link. Press control + space to open submenu.";
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("^(?:.*?goto\\(&#39;(\\w+)&#39;\\).*|.*?OOLPopUp\\(&#39;(.+?&#39;\\)).*)$", Pattern.MULTILINE);
 Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(s);
 while(matcher.find()){
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1) != null ?
                matcher.group(1) : matcher.group(2)
                );
}
```

Output:

```
billpay
findmyinfo
/myaccounts/brain/redirect.go?target=findmyroutingnumber&#39;,&#39;ool&#39;,&#39;currentPage&#39;)
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/8JBTEu)

Comment: I have another clarification and I hope you don't mind. I have another set of urls such as <a name='bill_pay' href='javascript:goto(\'billpay\');'>Bill Pay</a>, replacing &#39; with \'. I have tried to reverse engineer your regex, but nothing seems to be working. I get IndexOutOfBoundsException for every variation that I try. How can I add that as well?

Comment: Yes. That is precisely the effect I want. Although, we use single quotes in our HTML document, so we have a set up like <a name='bill_pay' href='javascript:goto(\'billpay\');'>Bill Pay</a>. I would like to be able to extract the value from here as well.

Comment: I am not able to put that in regex though.  Pattern.compile("^.*?(?:goto|OOLPopUp)\\(&#39;|'(.*?)&#39;|'\\).*", Pattern.MULTILINE); returns an ArrayOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: replace single backslash with double backslash

Comment: Where do I replace single backslash with doubleslash? Pattern.compile("^.*?(?:goto|OOLPopUp)\\(&#39;|\'(.*?)&#39;|\'\\).*", Pattern.MULTILINE); throw ArrayOutOfBoundsException

Answer (score 1):

You are always taking the group(1) that is the probem. Use

```
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Comment: No text is printed. The first entry is the entire string and then nothing.
I don't get the extracted strings.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your pattern. Try this:

```
Pattern.compile("goto\\(&#39;(\\w+)&#39;\\)",
                    Pattern.MULTILINE|Pattern.DOTALL);
```

Also in printing the result, you can try :

```
System.out.println(m.group(1) + " ( from " + str.substring(m.toMatchResult().start(), m.toMatchResult().end()) + " )");
```

the output is like this:

```
billpay (from goto(&#39;billpay&#39;);)
findmyinfo (from goto(&#39;findmyinfo&#39;);)
```