# Regular expression for year with optional closing parenthesis

Tags: java, regex

I am struggling to get the following regular expression (in Java) to work nicely. I want to see if a string has a year, and the strings can be

```
Mar 3, 2014
```

or sometimes with a closing parenthesis such as

```
Mar 3, 2014)
```

I am using

```
text.matches("\\b((19|20)\\d{2})(\\)?)\\b")
```

which works in most cases, but does not match if string ends at the parenthesis
If I use

```
text.matches("\\b((19|20)\\d{2})(\\)?)$")
```

it matches text that ends after the parenthesis but not a string that has another space

I thought that \b would include end of string, but cannot get it to work.

I know I can use two regex's but that seems really ugly.

Comment: Try enabling [multiline mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651725/match-multiline-text-using-regular-expression) so that `$` matches newlines not the end of strings..then you should be able to use your second expression.

Comment: can you tell us what are all possibilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is that `matches` checks if *entire* string matches regex. What you want is to test if string contains substring which can be matched by regex. To do so use

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(yourRegex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(stringYouWantToTest);
if (m.find()){
    //tested string contains part which can be matched by regex
}else{
    //part which could be matched by regex couldn't be found
}
```

You can also surround your regex with  `.*` to let it match characters beside part you wanted to find and use matches like you are doing now,

```
if(yourString.matches(".*"+yourRegex+".*"))
```

but this will have to iterate over entire string.

---

In other words you can try to find `\\b(19|20)\\d{2}\\b` using Pattern/Matcher or use something like `matches(".*\\b(19|20)\\d{2}\\b.*")`.

BTW parenthesis `)` are not included in `\w` class so `\b` will accept place between `\w` and `)` as word boundary so for instance `"9)"` will match regex `\d\b\)`.

Comment: That last BTW turned out to be the answer!  Putting the \b before the \)? instead of after did exactly what I wanted.  It becomees ((?:19|20)(?:\d){2})\b\)?

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear, but from what I understand, this should work for you:

```
text.matches("((?:19|20)(?:\\d){2})\\)?");
```

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/lO0aH4/3

Comment: That type of regex does not check for word endings, so that strings like "20147777" are also picked up.  I am trying to find a regex that will get both end of word and end of string.  Until I added the check for the optional ending ")", \b worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like :

```
".*(19|20)[0-9]{2}\\)?$"
```

I'm not sure it could help you, it would better to give us a complete example of string to match. Must the string be ended by a year (with optional parenthesis) or may it be something else after ?

Comment: The ending of the string is completely arbitrary.  I was checking for a 4 digit year surrounded by word boundaries, and that was working well.  I found that the check was getting fooled by the parenthesis and when I started checking for that, then the word boundary stopped working at end of string.