# Remove style tag from a text file with regex

Tags: java, regex

I need to remove style tags from text file..

I tried the following code

```
String text = readFile("E:/textwithstyletags.txt");
retVal = text.replaceAll("<style(.+?)</style>", "");
```

it works when the text file has style tags without new lines
i.e. `<style> body{ color:red; } </style>`

It doesn't work when there are new lines, like this

```
<style> 
body{ 
color:red; 
} 
</style>
```

Comment: Possibly related? [Match multiline text using regular expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651725/match-multiline-text-using-regular-expression)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `[\s\S]` in place of `.` in your regex

i.e:

```
retVal = text.replaceAll("<style([\\s\\S]+?)</style>", "");
```

Comment: please post the complete regex expression

Comment: @user3264864 use the above expression

Comment: invalid escape sequence

Answer (score 7):

Tested on [regex101](https://regex101.com/).

Pattern:

```
<style((.|\n|\r)*?)<\/style>
```

Your code:

```
String text = readFile("E:/textwithstyletags.txt");
retVal = text.replaceAll("<style((.|\\n|\\r)*?)<\\/style>", "");
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this regex:

```
retVal  = text.replaceAll("(?i)<style.*?>.*?</style>", "");
```

On a side note you can look at **[JSoup](http://jsoup.org/)** which is a java library made for HTML manipulation.

Comment: I like this, handles everything non-greedy and case insensitive, no muss no fuss.  Although I think you need to add the s flag (dot matches all) to handle linefeeds between open & close tags. like: `retVal  = text.replaceAll("(?is)<style.*?>.*?</style>", "");`

Answer (score 2):

you can use

this expression `<style[\\w\\W]+?</style>`

```
retVal = text.replaceAll("<style[\\w\\W]+?</style>", "");
```

It says to find all the alphanumeric character including the underscore(`\w`) and not word (`\W`) character  till `</script>`

Comment: use double back slash `\\w` and `\\W` @user3264864

Comment: <style[\\w\\W]+?<\\/style\\> It will do the job