# Error while using FileUtils

Tags: java, file, fileutils

I am using FileUtils from apache commons.io to search text between two strings in a file with the following code:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(fromDate) + "(.*?)" + Pattern.quote(toDate));

try {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(fileContent);                  
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
```

But there is an error it is giving output only when both the strings lie in same line, no output if strings are in at different lines? Here i am taking the content of whole file into a Sting Varibale "fileContent".

Answer (score 0):

The dot won't search over multiple lines. You need to give a second parameter for this `Pattern.DOTALL` like so:
`Pattern p = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(fromDate) + "(.*?)" + Pattern.quote(toDate), Pattern.DOTALL);`

Also this topics has some good explanation how it works: [Match multiline text using regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651725/match-multiline-text-using-regular-expression)

Comment: i thought to use this flag but now (?s) has solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try ending the regex with ?s so you new regex should be:
"(.*?s)"

In most case the matcher stops evaluate expression when it encounters a line feed \n.
?s make the matcher pass the \n when it try to match the regex.

Comment: I also tried with this "(?s)" and it is working properly. Anyway thanks for your suggestion