# Regex not matching prettily-printed file

Tags: java, regex

I'm just getting started with regexes so i might be doing some dumb mistakes here. I've got the following regex:

```
String regex = "length ?= ?\"[\\+-]?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?\".*height ?= ?\"[\\+-]\\d+(\\.\\d+)?\"";
```

This is matching this file/string properly:

```
<house length="120" prize="2000000" height="28"/>
```

but it's **not** matching

```
<house prize="2000000"
       length="-1200"
       owner="Smith"
       height="55.8"/>
```

I find this really weird since it should be matching the second one too... Any help pointing me into the right direction will be much appreciated!

Comment: What do you want to get as an output? - Value With/Without attribute

Comment: @MayurKoshti i just want to check whether there are 2 attributes length and height (with possible other attributes in between) and if the value of those contain a number with optional decimal dot.

Comment: Try this: 
`<house[^>]*length\=\"([^\"]+)\"[^>]*height=\"([^\"]+)\"[^>]*>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `.*` match any character except newline.

You need to add the [`s` modifier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL). You can find examples [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pattern.html).

Plus you forgot a `?` after your second `[\\+-]` case.

```
length ?= ?\"[\\+-]?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?\".*height ?= ?\"[\\+-]?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?\"
```

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/dP1zR7/1)

In java it will give you :

```
Pattern.compile("length ?= ?\"[\\+-]?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?\".*height ?= ?\"[\\+-]?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?\"", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

Remember that `String.matches()` doesn't work with flags but you can use `(?s)` in front of your string to make it work anyway.

Comment: ah ok, so the problem is that there are newlines between my attributes and `.` doesn't match newlines! As i see from the docs there are 2 possibilities to apply the `s` modifier. 1. writing `(?s)` in front of my string and 2. calling the compile method as `Pattern.compile(someStr, Pattern.DOTALL);` Is any of those ways recommended more than the other?

Comment: I would suggest you to use `Pattern.compile(someStr, Pattern.DOTALL);` since matching modes are supposed to be specified outside the regular expression. But I don't know if there is any real impact.

Comment: Thanks! This really helped me! (And i feel like a derp right now ;))

Answer (score 1):

You'll either need to account for the newlines and spaces using a character class (eg. `[\s\n]`) within your pattern or use `Pattern.MULTILINE` `(?m)` or `Pattern.DOTALL` `(?s)`.

- Stackoverflow: [Match Multiline Text Using Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651725/match-multiline-text-using-regular-expression)
- Oracle: [java.util.regex.Pattern Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Comment: The multiline isn't going to help him here.

Comment: @naurel: some explanation might be recommended.

Comment: He's trying to match a pattern ON multilines with a `.*`. The multiline modifier cause `^` and `$` to match the begin and the end of the line. It's not the question here. Using this method would complicate the regex far more.

Comment: @naurel: They are not using `^` `$` anchors ... and multiline mode can be used: https://regex101.com/r/yS9zH9/1. Every situation calls for different solutions, and knowing what the options are is important.

Comment: You're not matching the same thing as he is in your example. If you're able to do the same thing as he wants with multiline I would like to learn it.

Comment: Try it on the site that's linked... that's what it's there for :)

Answer (score 1):

this seems to work:

```
String regex="(.|\\s)* length ?= ?\"[\\+-]?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?\"(.|\\s)*height ?= ?\"[\\+-]?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?\"";
```

I replace .*, by (.|\s)* , added it at beginning, and replace [\+-]? at right, after height