# Strip part of multiline string using regex [JAVA]

Tags: java, regex, string

I am trying to filter some content from a file whose content is accessible to me as `String` as :

```
block "block1"
{
ADDSFDJF
SDFSDFSDF
SDFSDFSDF

 // subblock: subblock1 [master]
 include "/path/tofile/subblock1.conf";
+/- subblock subblock1
// subblock: subblock1
subblock "subblock1"
{
 type TYPE;
 file "name.file";
 details  blah blah.
 other {sdhsdf};
 };
};

 file "dddd.file";
 details  blah blah.

 // subblock: subblock2
 include "/path/tofile/subblock2.conf";
+/- subblock subblock2
// subblock: subblock2
subblock "subblock2"
{
 type TYPE;
 file "name.file";
 details  blah blah.
 other {sdhsdf};
 more fields
};
};
```

---

Here i want to delete some lines of each sub-block, i.e.: i want to remove these lines:

```
+/- subblock subblock1
// subblock: subblock1
subblock "subblock1"
{
 type TYPE;
 file "name.file";
 details  blah blah.
 other {sdhsdf};
 };
};
```

---

I was trying `content.replaceALL();`
but i am not able to create proper `regex` which matches `'+/-'` for start and proper closing '}' parenthesis for it.

Please help me through this.

**[EDIT]** : regex as a Java string

Comment: Yes white spaces may vary

Comment: i am able to do this in text editor using regex  \+\/\-[\s\S]+?//[\s\S]+?(^\};) 
but not in java using string "\\+\\/\\-[\\s\\S]+?//[\\s\\S]+?(^\\};)"

Comment: @ all down-voters i am new to stackoverflow i am not a player here..
will try to elaborate more from now onwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this through regex :

```
 (?m)\\+\\/\\-[\\s\\S]+?//[\\s\\S]+?(^\\};\\s+$)
```

as java string. or

```
 \+\/\-[\s\S]+?//[\s\S]+?(^\};\s+$)
```

as python regex.

Here, Pattern.MULTILINE or (?m) tells Java to accept the anchors ^ and $ to match at the start and end of each line (otherwise they only match at the start/end of the entire string).
Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3652392/5580576

See : 
[Demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/mY4yS9/2"Regex101") !!

Answer (score 0):

You **might** be able to get along with:

```
^\s*
subblock
[\s\S]+?
^\s*\};$
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/mY4yS9/1).
Note: you must double escape the backslashes in `Java`.

Comment: @ApoorvJain: You might then accept and/or upvote the answer (green tick on the left).