# Why doesn't my regexp work?

Tags: java, regex

Following code prints nothing. What am i doing wrong?
Regexp tester myregexp says that regular expression is correct.

```
page = "<div id=\"foo\" class=\"foo\" style=\"background-image: url(foo.jpg); width: 320px; height: 245px\">\n" +
                    "  <a href=\"foo\" onclick=\"return bar('foo', 'foo', {foo: bar, foo: bar}, foo)\"></a>\n" +
                    "</div>";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<div.*?</div>");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(page);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.start() + " " + matcher.end());
}
```

Comment: Consider using jsoup for parsing html: https://jsoup.org/

Comment: [Don't parse HTML using regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags), this is NOT the right tool for the job. As for your question, it probably doesn't work because it's multiline.

Comment: Thanks for advice. I'm already using jsoup, but my input html has some incorrect structure, so jsoup doesn't work either.

Comment: alfasin, multiline html, so what? I thought .*? will do the work.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Match multiline text using regular expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651725/match-multiline-text-using-regular-expression).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `.` in a regex does not match newlines. This means that your regex cannot match the `</div>` because the newline before it doesn't match `.`.

You should replace your compile line with:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<div.*?</div>",Pattern.DOTALL);
```

But as was noted in the comments, except in simple cases where you have control over the structure of the HTML (no comments, no Javascript, etc.), you should parse HTML with an HTML parser like JSoup, not using a regex.

Comment: Thanks for simple answer.