# Regular expression for finding the first character of every line

Tags: java, regex-replace

I need to find the first character of all the lines and remove it using Java.

Input lines:

```
Z301052023KDE12   0000.062500000 0000.000000000 0000.000000000
Z301052023KDE11   0000.000000000 0000.000000000 0000.000000000
```

Java code:

```
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        

        String inString = "Z302052023CFCL11   0000.000000000 249999.990        0999999990000.000000000 0000.000000000 0000.000000000 0000.000000000\n"
         + "Z302052023CFCL11   0000.000000000 249999.990        0999999990000.000000000 0000.000000000 0000.000000000 0000.000000000" ;
        
        String value = null;

        inString = inString.replaceAll("^.", "");
        System.out.println(inString);
    }
```

Output:

```
302052023CFCL11   0000.000000000 249999.990        0999999990000.000000000 0000.000000000 0000.000000000 0000.000000000
Z302052023CFCL11   0000.000000000 249999.990        0999999990000.000000000 0000.000000000 0000.000000000 0000.000000000
```

As you can see the 2nd line's first character is not removed.

Comment: `^.` in multiline mode

Comment: Hi @logi-kal, I tried this pattern in java but only first line's first character is getting selected.

Comment: Please look for for what multiline mode is.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651725

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Python:

```py
import re

input_lines = '''
Z301052023KDE12 0000.062500000 0000.000000000 0000.000000000
Z301052023KDE11 0000.000000000 0000.000000000 0000.000000000
'''

pattern = '^.'

first_chars = re.findall(pattern, input_lines, flags=re.MULTILINE)
print(first_chars)
```

Result:

```py
['Z', 'Z']
```

Comment: Hi Andreas, Thank you for the reply. Is the same pattern holds good for Java as well?

Comment: Hi @Andreas, I tried the pattern in Java but only first line's first character is getting selected.

Comment: I didn't actually answer the question, I just edited blvc3's answer. However, since you asked, it can be done like this in Java: `Pattern.compile("^.", Pattern.MULTILINE).matcher("Z301052023KDE12 0000.062500000\nZ301052023KDE11 0000.000000000").results().forEach(match -> System.out.println(match.group()));`. This is a one-liner to be readable as a comment, but you can break down its commands into multiple lines if it's not clear to you.