# KeyEvent uses unicode or ascii encoding?

Tags: java, unicode, ascii

I'm working on a project in Java. In my code I've JTextArea and I'm writing keyPressedEvent of JTextArea. The argument is of type `java.awt.event.KeyEvent`. When I use `evt.getKeyCode()` it returns me an `int` value. I wanna know that the returned value is `ASCII` value of character or `Unicode` value?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Java, is it possible to check if a String is only ASCII?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585053/in-java-is-it-possible-to-check-if-a-string-is-only-ascii)

Comment: Use KeyEvent.VK_KEYNAME

Comment: Java uses Unicode internally, it has never been limited to ASCII (fortunately so); now, a KeyEvent may, or may not, refer to a Unicode code point.

Comment: I got the answer at "Java Docs"
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html

KeyEvent uses unicode encoding. Here is the line explaining from the documentation
`They are generated when a Unicode character is entered, and are the preferred way to find out about character input.`

Comment: KeyCode use neither, it's an internal constant known as virtual key

Comment: @MadProgrammer your comment solved my problem.