# How To check whether the string of characters are ASCII in Java

Tags: java, performance, character-encoding

In order to check whether the string of characters are ASCII or not. Which one of the below is better choice ?

1. `java.nio.charset.Charset.forName("US-ASCII").newEncoder().canEncode("Desire
   character string to be checked")`or
2. Convert the String to character array and use :
   `org.apache.commons.lang.CharUtils.isAscii()`  method to check whether ASCII.

What are their differences, and which one is good performance wise. I know for the second option there is additional step of converting string to the character array first and then, need to check each character.

Comment: some more choices to do [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585053/in-java-is-it-possible-to-check-if-a-string-is-only-ascii)

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex as a quick shortcut.

```
String asciiText = "Hello";
System.out.println(asciiText.matches("\\A\\p{ASCII}*\\z"));
```

this will check only ASCII characters.

Regards.

Comment: `asciiText.matches("\\p{ASCII}*");`   Can be used to check ASCII, why have you used `asciiText.matches("\\A\\p{ASCII}*\\z")` ?

Comment: @NEO oops I thought you needed alphabets.

yes, asciiText.matches("\\p{ASCII}*"); would be fine