# Match if String contains only ASCII character set

Tags: java, android, string, ascii, guava

My problem is that I want to check if my **String** matches **ASCII**  character set.

I tried to use [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) library in my android project. The problem is that this library has too much weight (installed app size was 41 MB and with **Guava** library is become 45MB).

From **Guava** library I only need this:

```
CharMatcher.ascii().matchesAllOf();
```

Do you have any ideas how should i check my string correctly,or is there any other light-weight libraries?

Thanks!

Comment: Look at Guava source and copy that method and other call stack to your local. https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.java

Comment: @Nambari according to your answer i will not have any problems with licence?

Comment: @Diyarbakir Please read the question before flagging.

Comment: It's open source, AFAIK no license issues (but I have no authority to confirm that because I am not a contributor to that project).

Comment: You should go on with Guava, but shrink your jar file! https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/UsingProGuardWithGuava

Comment: `text.matches("\\A\\p{ASCII}*\\z")` is [Arne](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3585284/2226988)'s answer in linked question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The java code is:

```
public static boolean isAsciiPrintable(String str) {
  if (str == null) {
      return false;
  }
  int sz = str.length();
  for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
      if (isAsciiPrintable(str.charAt(i)) == false) {
          return false;
      }
  }
  return true;
  }
    public static boolean isAsciiPrintable(char ch) {
  return ch >= 32 && ch < 127;
  }
}
```

Ref: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Data-Type/ChecksifthestringcontainsonlyASCIIprintablecharacters.htm

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
private static boolean isAllASCII(String input) {
    boolean isASCII = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        int c = input.charAt(i);
        if (c > 0x7F) {
            isASCII = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return isASCII;
}
```

ref [In Java, is it possible to check if a String is only ASCII?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585053/in-java-is-it-possible-to-check-if-a-string-is-only-ascii)

Answer (score -2):

From [RealHowTo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/25122/realhowto)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3585247/3255152) to [In Java, is it possible to check if a String is only ASCII?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3585053/3255152)

> You can do it with [java.nio.charset.Charset](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html).
>
> ```
> import java.nio.charset.Charset;
> import java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder;
>
> public class StringUtils {
>
>   static CharsetEncoder asciiEncoder = 
>       Charset.forName("US-ASCII").newEncoder(); // or "ISO-8859-1" for ISO Latin 1
>
>   public static boolean isPureAscii(String v) {
>     return asciiEncoder.canEncode(v);
>   }
>
>   public static void main (String args[])
>     throws Exception {
>
>      String test = "Réal";
>      System.out.println(test + " isPureAscii() : " + StringUtils.isPureAscii(test));
>      test = "Real";
>      System.out.println(test + " isPureAscii() : " + StringUtils.isPureAscii(test));
>
>      /*
>       * output :
>       *   Réal isPureAscii() : false
>       *   Real isPureAscii() : true
>       */
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> [Detect non-ASCII character in a String](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0536.html)