# How to detect if a string does not contains other languages letters other than English letters?

Tags: java, string, character-encoding, char, special-characters

Consider a line like:

```
[Hello簲  bye 簲 ]
```

This line has both Chinese and English letters which is not of my interests. So I want to find out that if a string does not have any languages' letters other than English. Any idea?

**EDIT**
I do not want to solve it with `regex`. Otherwise I would have tagged it!

Comment: @Idos Please see my EDIT.

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/5238491/4517895

Comment: @MikhailChibel How to edit the answer of given link, so that the function accepts if the string contains digits and special characters? (like () <> ? ! etc)

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html

In class char, there is this:

getNumericValue(char ch)
Returns the int value that the specified Unicode character represents.

I believe you can do little more research to find unicode value of English letters so that you may check value of char is in range of English characters.

Comment: Of course, you have to break String to chars, but there could be easier way than breaking it up to individual chars.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use regexp, you can use below

```
    String str = "Hello簲  bye 簲";
    boolean isValid = true;
    for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
        if (!(c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') && !(c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')) {
            isValid = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(isValid);
```

Comment: How to edit this answer so that the function accepts if the string contains digits and special characters? (like () <> ? ! etc)

Comment: do you want to check all ASCII characters [0-127]?

Comment: yea, something like that. oh wait, only until 127

Comment: yes, need to check `(int)c < 128`

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585053/in-java-is-it-possible-to-check-if-a-string-is-only-ascii

Comment: at same if clause?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116296/discussion-between-saravana-and-lonesome).

Comment: i want like, sting can contain anything like alphabets, numbers, special characters but not the other language characters. how do we do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of **ASCII** values of all English characters in this program - digits, upper case and lower case alphabets (and also, blank spaces must be checked).

The **logic**: Iterate through each character of the String and check if the current character is an English character, i.e., its **ASCII** value lies between **48 and 57** (for numbers 0 - 9), **65 and 90** (for upper case alphabets) or **97 and 122** (for lower case alphabets) or is a **blank space**. If it's not any of these, then it's a non English character.

Here's the code:

```
String s = <-- THE STRING
int illegal = 0; //to count no. of non english characters
for(int i=0; i< s.length(); i++){
    int c = (int)s.charAt(i);
    if(!((c>=48 && c<=57)||(c>=65 && c<=90)||(c>=97 && c<=122)||((char)c == ' ')))
        illegal++;
}
if(illegal > 0)
System.out.print("String contains non english characters");
else
System.out.print("String does not contain non english characters");
```

**NOTE**: Make sure that the platform you're running the program on supports these characters. The **character encoding** for **Chinese** is either `Unicode` (Unicode supports almost all languages of the world) or `UTF-16`. Make sure to use this or even the `UTF-32` encoding while running the program and that the platform supports `UTF-16/32` if not `Unicode`.

I tested this code on my computer with the following test data:

```
String s = "abcdEFGH 745401 妈妈";
```

and I got the correct output as I ran this on Unicode. On platforms not supporting `Unicode` or `UTF-16/32`, the compiler treats the Chinese letters `妈妈` as `??????` and it may produce an error in the program. The Chinese letters, which become `??????` for the system will simply be ignored during execution and therefore the output of the above input I tested with would be `String does not contain non English characters` which is wrong. So in case you're running the program on an online Terminal/IDE or on a mobile phone, make sure to take care of this factor. You don't need to worry if you are running it on a windows/mac computer.

I hope it helps you.