# android CharsetEncoder.canEncode exception

Tags: android, character-encoding

Crashlytics has reported about the crash in my app:

Code:

```
asciiEncoder = Charset.forName("US-ASCII").newEncoder(); // or "ISO-8859-1" for ISO Latin 1
...
public static boolean isPureAscii(String v) {
    return asciiEncoder.canEncode(v);
}
```

Error:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ucnv_fromUnicode failed: U_ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT_ERROR
       at libcore.icu.NativeConverter.encode(NativeConverter.java)
       at java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoderICU.implFlush(CharsetEncoderICU.java:140)
       at java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder.flush(CharsetEncoder.java:464)
       at java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder.encode(CharsetEncoder.java:266)
       at java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder.canEncode(CharsetEncoder.java:202)
       at CorrectLocationUtfTokenizable.isPureAscii(CorrectLocationUtfTokenizable.java:38)
```

Device: ASUS T00J, Android OS: 5.0

The string to fail on is unknown, but it's not null.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the ASUS T00J implementation of this `libcore.icu.NativeConverter` has a bug on this edge case. 
You can try to catch `RuntimeException` inside `isPureAscii()`, and return false of anything is thrown. 
But Probably a cheaper method will work better:

```
public static boolean isPureAscii(String v) {
     return v==null? false: v.matches("\\A\\p{ASCII}*\\z");
}
```

([credit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3585284/1180898))