# Android How to avoid junk characters in a string while getting location from gps latitude/longitude

Tags: android, gps, location, latitude-longitude, google-geolocation

I am receiving a location address from GPS(Latitude/Longitude) programmatically; however, sometimes I receive a location address with special/unwanted characters.

When I send the addresses containing special/unwanted characters to the server, they are declined by the server.

Example 1: **, delhi, ä¸­å?½**

Example 2: **à¤¸à¥à¤•**

How can I prevent this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to avoid this problem and match all the characters are of  US-ASCII code point type.

```
String testText [] = new String[] { "delhi", "ä¸­å?½", 
    "à¤", "à¥à¤• ", "tessst½", "some valid test text1213"
};

for (String str : testText) {
    if (str.matches("\\A\\p{ASCII}*\\z")) {
        //do something
        Log.d("TAG", str + " - String is valid");
    }
}
```

If you are using Java 8 you can do it this way:

```
textInfoFromLocation.chars().allMatch(c -> c < 128)
```

In case if you just want to check each character, do the following:

```
for (Character c : str.toCharArray()) {
    if (c > 127) //character is invalid
        Log.d("TAG","Character " + c + " is invalid");
}
```

More information could be found in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585053/in-java-is-it-possible-to-check-if-a-string-is-only-ascii)

Comment: thank you Fedor. I have tried this. here am getting true/false only. i tried the above , delhi, ä¸­å?½ to check this string. am getting false only. even, i want to filter the string from the junk characters.